# What do the constraints "Rah" and "Ral" mean in extended inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, x86, x86-16, inline-assembly, ia16-gcc

This question is inspired by a question asked by someone on another forum. In the following code what does the extended inline assembly constraint `Rah` and `Ral` mean. I haven't seen these before:

```
#include<stdint.h>

void tty_write_char(uint8_t inchar, uint8_t page_num, uint8_t fg_color)
{
    asm (
        "int $0x10"
        :
        : "b" ((uint16_t)page_num<<8 | fg_color),
          "Rah"((uint8_t)0x0e), "Ral"(inchar));
}

void tty_write_string(const char *string, uint8_t page_num, uint8_t fg_color)
{
    while (*string)
        tty_write_char(*string++, page_num, fg_color);
}

/* Use the BIOS to print the first command line argument to the console */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
        tty_write_string(argv[1], 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

In particular are the use of `Rah` and `Ral` as constraints in this code:

```
asm (
    "int $0x10"
    :
    : "b" ((uint16_t)page_num<<8 | fg_color),
      "Rah"((uint8_t)0x0e), "Ral"(inchar));
```

The [GCC Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html#Constraints) doesn't have an `l` or `h` constraint for either [simple constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints) or x86/x86 [machine constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints). `R` is any legacy register and `a` is the *AX/EAX/RAX* register.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking at is code that is intended to be run in real mode on an x86 based PC with a BIOS. [`Int 0x10`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm) is a BIOS service that has the ability to write to the console. In particular [`Int 0x10/AH=0x0e`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm) is to write a single character to the TTY (terminal).

That in itself doesn't explain what the constraints mean. To understand the constraints `Rah` and `Ral` you have to understand that this code isn't being compiled by a standard version of GCC/CLANG. It is being compiled by a GCC port called [`ia16-gcc`](https://github.com/tkchia/gcc-ia16). It is a special port that targets 8086/80186 and 80286 and compatible processors. It doesn't generate 386 instructions or use 32-bit registers in code generation. This *experimental* version of GCC is to target 16-bit environments like DOS (FreeDOS, MSDOS), and [ELKS](http://elks.sourceforge.net/).

The documentation for `ia16-gcc` is hard to find online in HTML format but I have produced a copy for the recent [GCC 6.3.0 versions of the documentation on GitHub](https://mpetch.github.io/ia16-gcc-6.3.0/gcc/index.html). The documentation was produced by building ia16-gcc from source and using `make` to generate the HTML. If you review the machine constraints for Intel *IA-16—config/ia16* you should now be able to see what is going on:

> **Ral** The al register.
>
> **Rah** The ah register.

This version of GCC doesn't understand the `R` constraint by itself anymore. The inline assembly you are looking at matches that of the parameters for [Int 0x10/Ah=0xe](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm):

> ```
> VIDEO - TELETYPE OUTPUT
> AH = 0Eh
> AL = character to write
> BH = page number
> BL = foreground color (graphics modes only)
>
> Return:
> Nothing
>
> Desc: Display a character on the screen, advancing the cursor
>       and scrolling the screen as necessary
> ```

---

### Other Information

The documentation does list all the constraints that are available for the IA16 target:

> ```
> Intel IA-16—config/ia16/constraints.md
> a
> The ax register. Note that for a byte operand, 
> this constraint means that the operand can go into either al or ah.
>      
> b
> The bx register.
>
> c
> The cx register.
>
> d
> The dx register.
>
> S
> The si register.
>
> D
> The di register.
>
> Ral
> The al register.
>
> Rah
> The ah register.
>
> Rcl
> The cl register.
>
> Rbp
> The bp register.
>
> Rds
> The ds register.
>
> q
> Any 8-bit register.
>
> T
> Any general or segment register.
>
> A
> The dx:ax register pair.
>
> j
> The bx:dx register pair.
>
> l
> The lower half of pairs of 8-bit registers.
>
> u
> The upper half of pairs of 8-bit registers.
>
> k
> Any 32-bit register group with access to the two lower bytes.
>
> x
> The si and di registers.
>
> w
> The bx and bp registers.
>
> B
> The bx, si, di and bp registers.
>
> e
> The es register.
>
> Q
> Any available segment register—either ds or es (unless one or both have been fixed).
>
> Z
> The constant 0.
>
> P1
> The constant 1.
>
> M1
> The constant -1.
>
> Um
> The constant -256.
>
> Lbm
> The constant 255.
>
> Lor
> Constants 128 … 254.
>
> Lom
> Constants 1 … 254.
>
> Lar
> Constants -255 … -129.
>
> Lam
> Constants -255 … -2.
>
> Uo
> Constants 0xXX00 except -256.
>
> Ua
> Constants 0xXXFF.
>
> Ish
> A constant usable as a shift count.
>
> Iaa
> A constant multiplier for the aad instruction.
>
> Ipu
> A constant usable with the push instruction.
>
> Imu
> A constant usable with the imul instruction except 257.
>
> I11
> The constant 257.
>
> N
> Unsigned 8-bit integer constant (for in and out instructions).
> ```

There are many new constraints and some repurposed ones.

In particular the `a` constraint for the AX register doesn't work like other versions of GCC that target 32-bit and 64-bit code. The compiler is free to choose either *AH* or *AL* with the `a` constraint *if* the values being passed are 8 bit values. This means it is possible for the `a` constraint to appear twice in an extended inline assembly statement.

You could have compiled your code to a DOS EXE with this command:

```
ia16-elf-gcc -mcmodel=small -mregparmcall -march=i186 \
             -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99 -O3 int10h.c -o int10h.exe
```

This targets the 80186. You can generate 8086 compatible code by omitting the `-march=i186` The generated code for `main` would look something like:

```
00000000 <main>:
   0:   83 f8 01                cmp    ax,0x1
   3:   7e 1d                   jle    22 <tty_write_string+0xa>
   5:   56                      push   si
   6:   89 d3                   mov    bx,dx
   8:   8b 77 02                mov    si,WORD PTR [bx+0x2]
   b:   8a 04                   mov    al,BYTE PTR [si]
   d:   20 c0                   and    al,al
   f:   74 0d                   je     1e <tty_write_string+0x6>
  11:   31 db                   xor    bx,bx
  13:   b4 0e                   mov    ah,0xe
  15:   46                      inc    si
  16:   cd 10                   int    0x10
  18:   8a 04                   mov    al,BYTE PTR [si]
  1a:   20 c0                   and    al,al
  1c:   75 f7                   jne    15 <main+0x15>
  1e:   31 c0                   xor    ax,ax
  20:   5e                      pop    si
  21:   c3                      ret
  22:   31 c0                   xor    ax,ax
  24:   c3                      ret
```

When run with the command line `int10h.exe "Hello, world!"` should print:

> Hello, world!

---

**Special Note**: The IA16 port of GCC is very experimental and does have some code generation bugs especially when higher optimization levels are used. I wouldn't use it for mission critical applications at this point in time.