# Is Clang generating incorrect code for inline assembly?

Tags: c, clang, inline-assembly

I have some C code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct num {
    unsigned long long x;
} num;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct num anum;
    anum.x = 0;
    __asm__("movq %%rax, %0\n" : "=m" (anum.x) : "rax"(2));
    printf("%llu\n",anum.x);
}
```

which I'm compiling and running on my (Intel) Mac laptop.

The output from the code seems to be different depending on whether I compile with (GNU) GCC or Clang.
I compile with `gnucc -o gnu-test test.c` for GCC (I built `gnucc` from source on my Mac after downloading the source from https://gcc.gnu.org/install/download.html) and `clang -o clang-test test.c` for Clang (built-in macOS Clang).

On my Mac, with GNU, the result is `2` (which is what I expect). With Clang, the result is `140701838959608`.

The Clang result seems wrong to me, but I'm also wondering if, perhaps, my inline assembly isn't quite correct and GCC just happens to not expose my error.

I tried out the same code on [Compiler Explorer](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer) and the output there is also different for GCC (x86-64 GCC 13.2 gives `2`) and Clang (x86-64 Clang 16.0.0 gives `140726522786920`).

I tried disassembling the Clang binary with [`objdump -d`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump):

```
clang-test:    file format mach-o 64-bit x86-64

Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:

0000000100003f60 <_main>:
100003f60: 55                        pushq  %rbp
100003f61: 48 89 e5                  movq   %rsp, %rbp
100003f64: 48 83 ec 20               subq   $32, %rsp
100003f68: 89 7d fc                  movl   %edi, -4(%rbp)
100003f6b: 48 89 75 f0               movq   %rsi, -16(%rbp)
100003f6f: 48 c7 45 e8 00 00 00 00   movq   $0, -24(%rbp)
100003f77: 48 8d 45 e8               leaq   -24(%rbp), %rax
100003f7b: b9 02 00 00 00            movl   $2, %ecx
100003f80: 48 89 00                  movq   %rax, (%rax)
100003f83: 48 8b 75 e8               movq   -24(%rbp), %rsi
100003f87: 48 8d 3d 16 00 00 00      leaq   22(%rip), %rdi   ## 0x100003fa4 <_printf+0x100003fa4>
100003f8e: b0 00                     movb   $0, %al
100003f90: e8 09 00 00 00            callq  0x100003f9e <_printf+0x100003f9e>
100003f95: 31 c0                     xorl   %eax, %eax
100003f97: 48 83 c4 20               addq   $32, %rsp
100003f9b: 5d                        popq   %rbp
100003f9c: c3                        retq

Disassembly of section __TEXT,__stubs:

0000000100003f9e <__stubs>:
100003f9e: ff 25 5c 00 00 00         jmpq    *92(%rip)       ## 0x100004000 <_printf+0x100004000>
```

and `100003f80: 48 89 00 movq    %rax, (%rax)` seems to be the issue? Clang has the correct value in `ecx` and the correct address to write to in `rax`, but it does `movq    %rax, (%rax)` instead of `movq    %rcx, (%rax)`?

Comment: It does it correctly: https://godbolt.org/z/44oTGMxcY but only if you enable optimizations as your assumptions  are not valid without the optimizations

Comment: I hate gas syntax, but I can't find the expected "movq $0, %rax" instruction in the assembly output so I think something's wrong here.

Comment: @Joshua: Where were you expecting to see a mov-immediate of `0` to a register?  In a debug build (which this obviously is), `anum.x = 0;` compiles to `movq    $0, -24(%rbp)`.   (The `leaq    -24(%rbp), %rax` is preparing a register for `(%rax)` to be the addressing mode for `"=m"`.)  `movb    $0, %al` is zeroing AL to tell the variadic printf there are zero XMM register args.  `xorl    %eax, %eax` implements the implicit `return 0` at the bottom of `main`.  There's never any reason for a compiler to emit `movq $0` to a register; at most it'd use `movl $0, %eax` if not xor-zeroing.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm expecting to see the actual instruction in the asm block somewhere in the compiler output.

Comment: Anyway there's a reason I abandoned inline assembly long ago. It's too much trouble and much easier to use actual .asm files when you need asm for something.

Comment: Ah I see.  The asm template is `"movq %%rax, %0"`, also using AT&T syntax, so it's moving RAX to whatever the `%0` placeholder expands to (a lot like a printf format string, hence the %% to get a literal %).  `movq    %rax, (%rax)` is the expansion of the asm template.  (The compiler picked RAX for the address, and a different register the template didn't use for the `"rax"(2)` input constraint.)  This would be clearer if the OP looked at the compiler's asm output (`clang -S`) instead of disassembly, since then they could put a comment inside the asm template and make it super easy to find it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Clang is generating correct code, but you specified the incorrect constraint on the input operand.

The constraint (`"rax"`) is not interpreted as a register name. Instead, each letter in the constraint specifies an allowed operand type. The first letter here, `r`, allows using any general register, which makes the choice of `rcx` valid.

To constrain to the `rax` register, you need to use the `"a"` constraint. See the x86 section in the [machine constraints page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html).

```
__asm__("movq %%rax, %0\n" : "=m" (anum.x) : "a"(2));
```

Comment: This is unclear to me: should Asker remove the "r" from "rax" resulting in "ax", or is there some way to add another "a" somewhere?

Comment: @mtraceur `"rax"` is not treated as a register name, but as a combination of 3 different constraints r, a, and x. The correct way to specify a constraint on rax, eax, or ax (depending on the operand size) is the use the `"a"` constraint instead of `"rax"`.

Comment: interjay, so the constraints are union rather then intersection, I guess. In other words, `r` (any register) and `a` (ax-type register) would be permissively `r` rather than restrictively `a`?

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes. The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html) says: The simplest kind of constraint is a string full of letters, each of which describes one kind of operand that is permitted.

Comment: Just a side note: there is an experimental GCC port for ia86 that breaks with this tradition of one letter = one constraint. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62686259/what-do-the-constraints-rah-and-ral-mean-in-extended-inline-assembly

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying. Here's a +1, and I recommend adding "`"rax"` is not treated as a register name, but as a combination of 3 different constraints r, a, and x" and "when combining `r` (any register) and `a` (ax-type register), `r` wins" to the answer itself.